# Access trashed Wordpress posts on the front-end

Tags: wordpress, frontend, posts, recycle-bin

I've got this script to list all the post titles with permalinks including posts that are in the trash, on the front-end:

```
<ul>
<?php
$myposts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'offset' => 0,
    'category' => $cat_id,
    'post_status' => array('publish','trash')  
    )
);
foreach($myposts as $post) :
setup_postdata($post);
?>

    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</ul>
```

This works fine. But the problem is if I click on any of the post titles that are in the 'trash', I get the 404 page.

How can I access trashed posts on the front-end? I understand this the default Wordpress behaviour, but is there perhaps a function that allows trash posts to be viewed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm curious why you want to display trashed posts on the front-end, if you don't mind elaborating on that, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, only published posts are displayed by the main query for all users and additional private posts for logged in users. So we can use the `pre_get_posts` hook to add an additional post status to the main query

This is totally untested, not sure it will work, but you can try the following

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if (    $q->is_main_query()
         && $q->is_single() // can replace with $q->is_singular()
    ) {
        $q->set( 'post_status', array('publish','trash') );
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Pieter Goosen. It errors: 

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION)`

Comment: Sorry about that, had a missing comma. Fixed. Please see my updated code

Comment: Wow that works! Honestly I didn't think this was going to even be possible on the front-end. Cheers. Bounty awarded :-)

Update: When I attempt to award the bounty, it says "You may award your bounty in 21hrs". I'll come back in 21 hours :-)

Comment: My pleasure. You can even extend that and get the value of `post_status` first with `$status = $q->get( 'post_status' );` and then adding trashed to the result of `$status` and then adding that as value to your `post_status` parameter ;-). Enjoy

Comment: Great. Thank you ;-). Enjoy